# Android Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 error

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to solve this error but can't find any solution to solve my problem as I've tried all given links that's why I've to come here.

I'm trying to register user but can't. Please help me as this problem have already taken my whole day. Thanks in advance.

**My ApiClient.Java is here**

```
public class Apiclient {

static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

public static final String BASE_URL="http://MyIP/MYFoldername/";
public static Retrofit retrofit=null;

public static Retrofit getApiclient(){

    if (retrofit==null){
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

**User.Java class**

```
public class User {

private String response;
private String name;

public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

MainActivity

```
 public static PrefConfig prefConfig;
EditText txt_username, txt_email, txt_password;
Button buttonRegister;
TextView textViewSignIn;
public static ApiInterface apiInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    apiInterface = Apiclient.getApiclient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    txt_email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    txt_username = findViewById(R.id.name);
    txt_password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    buttonRegister = findViewById(R.id.register);
    textViewSignIn = findViewById(R.id.signin);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            register();
        }
    });
}

private void register() {

    final String userName = txt_username.getText().toString();
    final String email = txt_email.getText().toString();
    final String password = txt_password.getText().toString();


    Call<User> call = MainActivity.apiInterface.performReg(userName, email, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            assert response.body() != null;
            if (response.body().getResponse().equals("ok")) {
                MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast("REGISTER");
            } else if (response.body().getResponse().equals("exist")) {
                MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast("EXIST");
            } else if (response.body().getResponse().equals("error")) {
                MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast("ERROR");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Here is my json Picture]

Answer (score 0):

The Code you have written is correct, but I think the result is something rather than JSON formatted String. Maybe this happens because of your test mobile device network connection to MyIP server.

To test the situation, try to get the response from server using String, instead of User, and make sure that the response is the same as what you receive in PostMan.